# Xcode file disabled/deleted

Tags: macos, xcode

My computers hard drive is full, and while I edited a .h file in xcode it said it can't be autosaved (obviously), but then the file name in the navigation area turned red and I wasn't able to get into the file. This happened to two files, and one of them went available again after deleting some files but one isn't even though I have cleared space. I can't seem to find it in the project directory neither. What has happened, is my file deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the Xcode the filename turns red, that means that Xcode is missing reference to the file, which can mean that the file is either deleted or renamed.

Comment: nice catch, have more of those, here is the place to show them :)